# How to ping an ip and get only the ms on MS-DOS

Tags: dos

I can normally type

```
ping 8.8.8.8 -n 1
```

and i see output:

```
Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=84ms TTL=46

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 84ms, Maximum = 84ms, Average = 84ms
```

Is there anyway that I can see only **84** as output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=mu= " %%a in ('ping 8.8.8.8 -n 1 ^|find "mum"') do echo %%a
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I didnt understand why you used " delims=mu= " also what does " ^ " stands for?

Comment: `^` escapes the pipe character and is used inside the `for` command line for several characters like `< and > and &  and |`. The `m` and `u` and `=` characters are used as delimiters.  Read http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html and you will get an idea how delimiters and tokens are used.

Comment: I completely understood what you meant. Now I'm wondering how we can type a universal code because only english operating systems can profit